# What are the programming tools used to build an Android game like Elevate?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-engine, google-play-games

The idea is how to build an android game that contains inside it many small games like Snake, draw letters, Sudoku...(Elevate as an example)

Should I use Android native, ionic, unity…?

Note that Elevate has incredible animations.
[Elevate in Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wonder&hl=en)

Comment: Yes me too have same question! I'm wondering how they would have developed such an amazing app! Best Android app i have ever seen ❤️!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost certain it's a native app based on the standard UI widgets (e.g. [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html), [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html), [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html)) it uses.

With that being said, you can surely build such an app with other tools like Unity or even Game Maker Studio. However, implementing UI widgets that mimic native Android functionality can prove difficult and time-consuming.

My recommendation would be to use an IDE such as Android Studio and utilize Google's vast UI libraries to build the menu sections of the app.

As for the mini-games, it all comes down to managing resources and memory (making sure that resources for a particular game are loaded in/out of memory as needed).

Comment: That's useful. thanks

Comment: @user9514304 I seriously doubt that they have used just the native components that you have mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry.. To Say that. It doesn't looks like a real game. Unity 3D is a heavy engine which is highly recommended for big games. But still if you want to build it in Unity the i suggest you the following tools:

Game Engine: Unity 3D.
Database: Firebase.
Animations: Adobe Illustrator.